# Is there any api for "chunk_download" for dropbox like upload

Tags: python, download, dropbox, dropbox-api

By the word "chunk_download", i mean, is there any robust api for downloading files from dropbox.
The api(python) i used is

```
for media in dbx.files_list_folder("/"+ directory).entries:
    dbx.files_download_to_file(path_local_machine, path_dropbox)
```

- but the above api is not robust and may fail in case of network
  timeout situations.
- Is there any way to find the progress of download?
- how to handle the exception in case of network error and how to continue the download again?

Answer (score 1):

API v2 doesn't (*yet*) support this, but Core API v1 does. From https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#files-GET:

> This method also supports [HTTP Range Retrieval Requests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2) to allow retrieving partial file contents.

I don't think a means to do this is exposed in the Python SDK, but you can make your own HTTP requests to v1 and use the `Range` header.

Comment: Thank you smarx. the link [github feature link]https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/issues/37 is a feature request in github for adding the progress to the v2 api. I don't understand the workaround he says in the link. the **files_download** api returns a tuple, (metadata and a request object). These are returned only after the file is downloaded. How can i use the request object before that, so that i can invoke .read(4096) to get the progress and make other robust features. I am confused. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you could ask that question there.